# Giving a single sub directory multiple names via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, directory

**Primary Scenario** ( Answer Needed )

If my website `http://website.com` has multiple subdirectories:

`/features/` . `/articles/` . `/projects/`

Which all contain their any number of files and folders;

Is there a way to change the name of a leading directory?

For example:

```
http://website.com/content/features/( ... )

Becomes

http://website.com/public/features/( ... )

AND

http://website.com/private/features/( ... )
```

--

**Former Scenario** ( On Hold )

Lets say I have a website hosted on `http://website.com`.

And I would like to add a few personalised projects in a sub section of the site, for example `/extra/`.

So, lets say I have:

```
/extra/feature.php?subject=( a childrens cartoon )
/extra/article.php?subject=( fetish photography project )
/extra/ebook.php?subject=( local golfing borchure )
```

Is there a way to apply an alias to the `extra` directory, so that it becomes two or more other names? For example:

```
/extra/feature.php?subject=( a childrens cartoon )

Becomes

/public/feature.php?subject=( a childrens cartoon )

And

/private/feature.php?subject=( a childrens cartoon )
```

I assume this would be possible with `htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to `Scenario 1` is simply 2 lines of code placed in a `.HTACCESS` file, within the root directory of `http://website.com`.

The code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?:public|private)/(.*) extra/$1
```

Now, visiting `http://website.com/extra/(directory)`, `http://website.com/public/(directory)`, or `http://website.com/private/(directory)` will all show the same destination files.

Any other `/name/` will result in an `error 404`.

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess` you can use mod_rewrite to *internally rewrite* the URL from `/public/` to `/extra/`.

For example, to rewrite only URLs of the form `.../feature.php?subject=<something>` you could do something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^subject=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^(?:public|private)/(feature\.php)$ /extra/$1 [L]
```

This matches URLs of the form `/public/feature.php?subject=<something>` or `/private/feature.php?subject=<something>` and rewrites the request to `/extra/feature.php?subject=<something>`. This is an internal rewrite, the URL in the address bar does not change.

The `?:` in `(?:public|private)` makes the subpattern non-capturing, since we don't need this in the *substitution* string (aka target URL).

`(feature\.php)` - This is a capturing subpattern and is referenced in the *substitution* using the `$1` backreference. This simply saves typing (and potential errors). However, you could also group `article.php` and `ebook.php` together to handle all three instances with a single directive.

The `RewriteCond` directive is necessary in order to match the query string. The `RewriteRule` only matches the URL-path.

The query string from the requested URL is passed through to the target URL by default, so you do not need to do anything with the query string.

Comment: Thank you. Two questions though ... 1) Would the htaccess file be located in `extra`? ... 2) As you've used a `|` between `public` and `private` am I right in assuming that you could have multiple other file names? If so, would you recommend a limit to the number of names you use?

Comment: 1) These directives would need to go in the `.htaccess` in the document root, not in the `/extra` subdirectory. (I've updated my answer.) Assuming `/public` and `/private` don't exist as physical directories then these requests only reach your root directory, until they are rewritten. 2) Yes, you can have multiple other "virtual directory" names. The limit is really determined by readability. Too many and it's simply harder to read. This can be split into multiple conditions if you wish.

Comment: "used a `|` between `public` and `private`" - the whole argument is a regular expression (regex). The `|` (vertical bar) is used to express _alternation_ in regex. The surrounding parentheses `(`...`)` limits the alternation to just that group of characters. https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. I'll be trying this out on my website later on. I can't give you an upvote as I don't have 15 reputation, but if all works well I'll accept your answer once tested

Comment: Gave this a try but there's something wrong. When I visit `/extra/feature/example`, I'm shown the correct page. But when I change `extra` to `public` I'm shown `Not Found : The requested URL ... was not found on this server.`

Comment: I've also updated my scenario. Seems a bit easier to find a solution to but I'm not 100% sure.